# Invoke NServiceBus Saga as a single awaitable request-response

Tags: c#, rest, architecture, microservices, nservicebus

Consider a web application that implemented every database action except querying (i.e. add, update, remove) as a NServiceBus message, so that whenever a user calls a web API, in the back-end it will be mapped to `await endpointInstance.Request` method to return the response in the same HTTP request connection.

The challenge is when a message handler needs to send some other messages and wait for their response to finish its job. NServiceBus does not allow to call `Request` inside a message handler.

I ended up using Saga to implement message handlers that are relied on some other message handler responses. But the problem with Saga is that I can't send back the result in the same HTTP request, because Saga uses publish/subscribe pattern.

All our web APIs need to be responded in the same HTTP request (connection should be kept open until the result is received or a timeout exception occurred). 
Is there any clean solution (preferably without using Saga)?

An example scenario:

1. user call http://test.com/purchase?itemId=5&paymentId=133
2. web server calls `await endpointInstance.Request<PurchaseResult>(new PurchaseMessage(itemId, paymentId));`
3. `PurchaseMessage` handler should call `await endpointInstance.Request<AddPaymentResult>(new AddPaymentMessage(paymentId));`
4. if the `AddPaymentResult` was successfull, store the purchase details in the database and return `true` as `PurchaseResult`, otherwise return `false`

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to achieve something that we (at Particular Software) are trying to actively prevent. Let me explain.

With Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) you call another component out-of-process. That what makes the procedure call 'remote'. Where with regular programming you do everything in-process and it is blazing fast, with RPC you have the overhead of serialization, latency and more. Basically, you have to deal with [the fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing).

Still, people do it for various reasons. Sometimes because you want to use a WebAPI (or 'old fashioned' web service) because it offers the functionality you don't want to develop. Oldest example in the book is searching for an address by postal code. Or deducting money from someone's bank account. If you're building a CRM, you can use these remote components. These days a lot of people build distributed monoliths because they are taught at conferences that this is a good thing. In an architecture diagram, it looks really nice, but there's still temporal coupling that can provide a lot of headaches.

Some of these headaches come from the fact that you're trying to do stuff in an atomic action. Back in the days, with in-process calling of code/classes/etc this was easy and fast. Until you hit limitations, like tons of locks on a database.

A solution to this is asynchronous communication. You send some information via fire-and-forget. This solves temporal coupling. Instead of having a database that is getting dozens and dozens of requests to update data, etc. and as a result, your website is grinding to a halt, you have various options to make sure this doesn't happen. This is a really good thing, because instead of a single atomic operation, you have various smaller operations and many ways to distributed work, scale your system, etc, etc.

It also brings additional challenges, because not everyone is able to work with fire-and-forget. Some systems that were already built, try to introduce asynchronous communication via messaging (and hopefully NServiceBus). Some parts can work flawlessly with this. But others parts can't. Mainly the user-interface (UI). Because it was built to get an immediate result. So when you send a message from the UI, you expect a result!

With NServiceBus we've built a package called "Client-Side Callbacks" to make exactly this a possibility. We highly recommend our customers not to use it, except for this specific scenario that I just described. It is much better to migrate your entire UI to be able to deal with the fact that you don't receive an immediate answer, but we understand this is so much work, that not many will be able to achieve this.

However once that first message was sent and the UI received a result, there is no need to use callbacks anymore. As a result I'd like to propose this scenario:

1. use call http://test.com/purchase?itemId=5&paymentId=133
2. web server calls `await endpointInstance.Request<PurchaseResult>();`
3. `PurchaseMessage` handler retrieves info it needs and sends or publishes a message to (an)other component(s) and then replies back to the web server with an answer.
4. The next handler works with the send/published message and continues the process

Let us know if you need more information. You can always contact us by sending an email to support@particular.net

Comment: Thank you @Dennis for your good explanation. However as you know web services usually are expected to respond immediately. Otherwise the caller should  periodically call another Web API to see if the result is there or not (or the server itself informs the caller say by using a websocket connection), am I right? Anyway is there a way to make a `request` inside a message handler? AFAIK "Client-Side Callbacks" package does not allow it.

Comment: IMHO a workaround for publish/subscribe pattern could be to make an API layer which map every user request to a normal send/publish message, and keep the connection open until the correlated message (the response from related services) is published in the bus. Is this a good solution or workaround?